# Check if app launched via today widget on iOS...?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, openurl

When I open the `App` from my `Today Extension` with this method :

```
open func open(_ URL: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

My app's life cycle goes this way :

- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- viewDidLoad (initial ViewController)
- openURL

This annoys me because I want to set my `launchState` variable to **widget** and do custom logic in my **initial** `ViewController` which I can't if the `openURL` method is the last one triggered.

How can I handle this scenario ?

**EDIT:**

The user can open the App from the Today Extension, or the Classic launch.
In the `viewDidLoad` of the rootViewController I am doing this :

```
fileprivate func prepareCityToLaunch() {

    switch launchState {
         case .widget:
             launchCity.getWidgetCity()
         case .classic:
             launchCity.getLaunchCity()
    }
}
```

Which is an enum, by default it is set to `.classic`, and I am setting it to `.widget` in the openURL method.

This methods return the appropriate `City` object to request for thank to delegation.

I can't wait for the `Notification` from `openURL` because in this `viewController` I don't know yet if the App is open from `Widget` or from `Classic` launch and because the launchState is set to classic by default, it will always get the city as if the App is launched in the classic way.

That is why I wanted to set the launchState first in the openURL method, then in my viewDidLoad everything would have been set correctly.

Is it understandable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show a loader/empty value inside the vc , then using `NSNotificationCenter` from inside `openURL` to set needed value

**OR**

Set a suite shared user default between your app and the widget to know that and give it a value before the line that directs to the app  , and check it's value inside `viewDidLoad` of the vc ,  then  set it to nil

Comment: This is the solution I went for (UserDefaults). Thank you for confirming that this is the right way to go.

Comment: This is more of a hack. Look at my answer for the exact solution. @Balanced

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative and better solution.
Add the following lines in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and make a check for bundle identifier of your today widget.

```
    if let value = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, value == "com.company.app.todayWidget" {
        //Launched via today widget
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using SwiftUI, add `.widgetURL(deeplinkURL)` to it and handle it inside of your main app's `SceneDelegate`.

```swift
struct MyWidget: View {

  private static let deeplinkURL = URL(string: "some-deeplink-scheme://optionalOtherStuff")!

  var body: some View {
    Text(entry.date, style: .time)
      .widgetURL(deeplinkURL)
  }
}
```

Also make sure to add that custom url scheme to your project settings inside of your app's target's info tab under `URL Types`

[image: Add custom url scheme to project settings for deeplink handling]

For a more complete answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715553/1898677
and https://www.donnywals.com/handling-deeplinks-in-your-app/