# Detect app launch from WidgetKit widget extension

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

Tapping a WidgetKit widget automatically launches its parent application. How can I detect if my application was launched from its WidgetKit widget extension?

I'm unable to find any documentation on capturing this in the applications `AppDelegate` and/or `SceneDelegate`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To detect an app launch from a WidgetKit widget extension where the parent application supports scenes you'll need to implement [scene(_:openURLContexts:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene), for launching from a background state, and [scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene), for launching from a cold state, in your parent application's `SceneDelegate`. Also, add [widgetURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/widgeturl(_:)) to your widget's view.

Widget's `View`:

```
struct WidgetEntryView: View {
    
    var entry: SimpleEntry
    
    private static let deeplinkURL: URL = URL(string: "widget-deeplink://")!

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
            .widgetURL(WidgetEntryView.deeplinkURL)
    }
    
}
```

Parent application's `SceneDelegate`:

```
// App launched
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _: UIWindowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    maybeOpenedFromWidget(urlContexts: connectionOptions.urlContexts)
}

// App opened from background
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    maybeOpenedFromWidget(urlContexts: URLContexts)
}

private func maybeOpenedFromWidget(urlContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let _: UIOpenURLContext = urlContexts.first(where: { $0.url.scheme == "widget-deeplink" }) else { return }
    print(" Launched from widget")
}
```

Comment: Why about apps doesn't support scene delegate? can implement from AppDelegate?

Comment: I am doing without swift ui excepts widgets support.
How can I handle without scene delegate?

Comment: Which method gets callback in Objective c??

Comment: For Objective C and Older projects you can use this function to intercept the URL `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options`

Comment: @iOS.Lover Per [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension) it depends on which you have implemented. "When the widget receives an interaction, the system activates the containing app and passes the URL to onOpenURL(perform:), application(_:open:options:), or application(_:open:), depending on the life cycle your app uses."

Answer (score 12):

#### SwiftUI 2 life cycle

1. Add `widgetURL` to your Widget view:

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

    private static let deeplinkURL = URL(string: "widget-deeplink://")!

    var body: some View {
        Text("Widget")
            .widgetURL(Self.deeplinkURL)
    }
}
```

2. Detect if the app is opened with a deeplink in `onOpenURL`:

```
@main
struct WidgetTestApp: App {
    @State var linkActive = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Opened from Widget"), isActive: $linkActive).hidden()
                    Text("Opened from App")
                }
            }
            .onOpenURL { url in
                guard url.scheme == "widget-deeplink" else { return }
                linkActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#deeplink-widget) with different Widget examples including the DeepLink Widget.</sub>

Comment: openUrl doesn't get called :( I have app delegate and scenedelegate implemented. Any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

If you are setting widgetURL or Link control for Widget UI then containing app opens with `application(_:open:options:)`. You can set additional data in URL to know source.

If you are not using widgetUrl or link control then containing app opens with `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` and `userInfo` has `WidgetCenter.UserInfoKey`. That should tell you App opened from widget and information about user's interaction.

Comment: Only if app was terminated beforehand..

Answer (score 0):

We can also detect from which widget the app is launched.
Specify a unique URL scheme for each widget kind like this:

```
struct PhotoWidgetExtensionEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry
private static let smallWidgetDeepLinkURL = URL(string: "small-widget-deeplink://")!
private static let mediumWidgetDeepLinkURL = URL(string: "medium-widget-deeplink://")!
private static let largeWidgetDeepLinkURL = URL(string: "larege-widget-deeplink://")!
@Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
var body: some View {
    switch widgetFamily {
    case .systemSmall:
        Text("Small Widget")
            .widgetURL(Self.smallWidgetDeepLinkURL)
    case .systemMedium:
        IText("Medium Widget")
            .widgetURL(Self.mediumWidgetDeepLinkURL)
    case .systemLarge:
        Text("Large Widget")
            .widgetURL(Self.largeWidgetDeepLinkURL)
    default:
        Text("Large Widget")
            .widgetURL(Self.largeWidgetDeepLinkURL)
      }
   }
}
```

Then handle each scheme in the main app:

```
struct WidgetifyApp: App {
@State var linkActive = false
@State var widgetKind = ""
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ContentView().environmentObject(ImageManager())
                    .onOpenURL { url in
                        switch url.scheme {
                        case "small-widget-deeplink":
                            widgetKind = "Small"
                        case "medium-widget-deeplink":
                            widgetKind = "Medium"
                        case "large-widget-deeplink":
                            widgetKind = "Large"
                        default:
                            widgetKind = "Unknown"
                        }
                        linkActive = true
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $linkActive) {
                        Text("Opened from \(widgetKind) Widget")
                    }
              }
          }
       }
    }
}
```