# Perform a deeplink from SwiftUI widget on tap

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I have a simple widget (medium-sized) with two texts, and what I want is to be able to perform a deep link to lead the user to a specific section of my app, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

The view I have written (which is very simple):

```
HStack {
    Text("FIRST ITEM")    
    Spacer()
    Text("SECOND ITEM")
}
```

I have already tried to replace

```
Text("SECOND ITEM")
```

with

```
Link("SECOND ITEM destination: URL(string: myDeeplinkUrl)!)
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. In the **Widget** view you need to create a `Link` and set its `destination` url:

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Link(destination: URL(string: "widget://link1")!) {
            Text("Link 1")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `Link` works in *medium* and *large* Widgets only. If you use a *small* Widget you need to use:

```
.widgetURL(URL(string: "widget://link0")!)
```

2. In your **App** view receive the url using `onOpenURL`:

```
@main
struct WidgetTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("Test")
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    print("Received deep link: \(url)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It is also possible to receive deep links in the `SceneDelegate` by overriding:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)
```

You can find more explanation on how to use this function in this thread:

- [Detect app launch from WidgetKit widget extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63697132/8697793)

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#deeplink-widget) with different Widget examples including the DeepLink Widget.</sub>

Comment: How is the link for .widgetUrl specified? How to define this url for a particular location in an app? Correct me if I am wrong but I think the first part of the url shows the URL scheme specified in the info section of the app but I am not able to figure out what exactly the second part of the url is?

Comment: @Krits Every url from the widget will be opened in the app. So the `scheme` can be a way to differentiate widget urls from other urls (e.g. from user notifications). The other path components can specify an action/location - it's up to you. You just need to use `onOpenURL(url:)` in a specific view and check if a particular URL arrived.

Comment: So as mentioned in the above question, "widget://link0". What exactly link0 and link1 are? And how do we specify the action and or location in this url?

Comment: @Krits It's just a custom text describing the action. In `onOpenURL(url:)` you just check which url arrived (if it's link0 or link1...) and perform some action (show an alert, activate a navigation link...).

Comment: Hi, can you please specify where exactly should I put onOpenUrl(url: ) in my app because I have created my app using Storyboard.

Comment: beautiful and complete answer

Answer (score 12):

Also, you can do it using `AppDelegate` (if you not using `SceneDelegate`):

```
.widgetURL(URL(string: "urlsceheme://foobarmessage"))

// OR

Link(destination: URL(string: "urlsceheme://foobarmessage")!) {
    Text("Foo")
}
```

Set this code within `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
   let message = url.host?.removingPercentEncoding // foobarmessage
   return true
}
```

Comment: using above code i am not getting any message in AppDelegate any suggestion to cross check setup ?

Answer (score 4):

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension) on: **Respond to User Interactions**

When users interact with your widget, the system launches your app to handle the request. When the system activates your app navigates to the details that correspond to the widget’s content. Your widget can specify a URL to inform the app what content to display. To configure custom URLs in your widget:

- For all widgets, add the `widgetURL(_:)` view modifier to a view in your widget’s view hierarchy. If the widget’s view hierarchy includes more than one `widgetURL` modifier, **the behavior is undefined**.
- For widgets that use `WidgetFamily.systemMedium` or `WidgetFamily.systemLarge`, add one or more Link controls to your widget’s view hierarchy. You can use both `widgetURL` and `Link` controls. If the interaction targets a `Link` control, the system uses the URL in that control. For interactions anywhere else in the widget, the system uses the `URL` specified in the `widgetURL` view modifier.

For example, a widget that displays details of a single character in a game can use `widgetURL` to open the app to that character’s detail.

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        AvatarView(entry.character)
            .widgetURL(entry.character.url)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .background(Color.gameBackground)
}
```

If the widget displays a list of characters, each item in the list can be in a `Link` control. Each Link control specifies the `URL` for the specific character it displays.

When the widget receives an interaction, the system activates the containing app and passes the URL to `onOpenURL(perform:)`, `application(_:open:options:)`, or `application(_:open:)`, **depending on the life cycle your app uses**.

If the widget doesn’t use `widgetURL` or `Link` controls, the system activates the containing app and passes an `NSUserActivity` to `onContinueUserActivity(_:perform:)`, `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`, or `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`. The user activity’s userInfo dictionary contains details about the widget the user interacted with. Use the keys in `WidgetCenter.UserInfoKey` to access these values from Swift code. To access the userInfo values from Objective-C, use the keys `WGWidgetUserInfoKeyKind` and `WGWidgetUserInfoKeyFamily` instead.