# How to perform deeplink from widget to parent app in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

My application is a `UIKit` app (Swift + Objective-C), not a `SwiftUI` app.
After implementing this new `WidgetKit` how can I perform deeplink from widget to my app?

Which method in `AppDelegate` I will get the callback?

Check the code below:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
            .widgetURL(widgetsEntryView.deeplinkURL)
    }
}
```

If I create the project in Swift then I am getting the callback on:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

}
```

Tried `Link` also. Can someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a deeplink from SwiftUI widget on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230355/perform-a-deeplink-from-swiftui-widget-on-tap)

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64297619/8697793

Comment: No it doesn't. Objective C call back method is not there. It works fine for me If I use swift and swiftui. Not in Objective c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which method in AppDelegate I will get the callback?

You can use [`application:openURL:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options;
```

Comment: Thank you @pawello2222 !!
Just wanted to add couple of notes from my own test (**lock screen widget** - small size), containing app is written on Obj-C:
**If app in cold state/terminated, _ex: kill the app from xcode_, `openURL :` is not called, nor other related `appDelegate` methods.
** If using `Link` instead of `widgetLink`, `openURL:` is not called, instead both `willContinueUserActivityWithType:` and `continueUserActivity:` are called and `webpageURL` is null