# Open UIViewController from iOS14 WidgetKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, deep-linking, appdelegate, widgetkit

I have a very simple app flow. **ParentVC** and **ChildVC**. In the ParentVC, I have a collection view and on its didSelectItem, the ChildVC opens up with the relative content. Now I have used iOS 14 WidgetKit to create Small & Medium size widgets which when app goes to background, stores the **PageTitle** of of the ChildVC and shows that on the WidgetUI.

My requirement is: How can I open that particular **ChildVC** when I tap on the Widget?

PS: I am using **AppDelegate** and not SceneDelegate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a deeplink from SwiftUI widget on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230355/perform-a-deeplink-from-swiftui-widget-on-tap)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your Appdelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let vcNext = UIStoryboard(name: "nameYourStoryBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdentifierOfViewController") as! YourViewController
    let tabbar = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController

    let navcontrol = tabbar?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    navcontrol?.pushViewController(vcNext, animated: true)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   return true
}
```