# Home widget: Is there a way to launch the desired view controller, without launching the parent main view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, when I tap on the home widget, it will first launch the parent main view controller, then only launch my desired view controller (an editor view controller in yellow color)

### Demo video

[image]

I was wondering, is there a way to launch my desired view controller **directly**, without having to launch the parent main view controller?

Here's the code snippets.

### Home widget code

```
struct sticky_note_widgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    private let widgetURLTemplate = "xxx://widget?objectIDAsString="

    @ViewBuilder
    func contentView(stickyNote: StickyNote, showTitleBar: Bool, showImageAttachments: Bool, widgetWidth: Double) -> some View {
        let url = URL(string: widgetURLTemplate + objectIDAsString)

        let contentView = VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        }
        .widgetURL(url)

        contentView
    }
}
```

### SceneDelegate code

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    static var incomingURL: URL? = nil
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697132/detect-app-launch-from-widgetkit-widget-extension
        if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url {
            if SceneDelegate.handleIncomingURL(url) {
                SceneDelegate.incomingURL = nil
            } else {
                SceneDelegate.incomingURL = url
            }
        } else {
            SceneDelegate.incomingURL = nil
        }
    }
    
    // Called on existing scenes
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        if let url = URLContexts.first?.url {
            _ = SceneDelegate.handleIncomingURL(url)
        }
    }
    
    // Return false, if we should retry later on.
    static func handleIncomingURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        if let scheme = url.scheme, scheme == "xxx", let page = url.host {

            var parameters: [String: String] = [:]
            URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.forEach {
                parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
            }

            // Retry required.
            guard let rootViewController = UIWindow.key?.rootViewController else { return false }
              
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520899/single-function-to-dismiss-all-open-view-controllers
            // Dismiss all previous launched VC except root view controller.
            rootViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            
            switch page {
            case "widget":
                guard let objectIDAsString = parameters["objectIDAsString"] else { return true }
                guard let objectID = NSManagedObjectID.from(objectIDAsString) else { return true }
                
                if let rootViewController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                    // TODO: rootViewController is parent main view controller.
                    //
                    // We are launching the desired yellow view controller
                    // from parent main view controller.
                    // Is there a way to launch the yellow view controller directly,
                    // without having to show parent main view controller?
                    // 
                    Utils.handleEditNote(rootViewController: rootViewController, objectID: objectID)
                }

            default:
                precondition(false)
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

### Parent main view controller code

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        handleIncomingURLIfPossible()
    }

    private func handleIncomingURLIfPossible() -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = SceneDelegate.incomingURL {
            SceneDelegate.incomingURL = nil

            SceneDelegate.handleIncomingURL(incomingURL)
            
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its because of your routing logic. Can you make a minimum project and put it on the git so that others can contribute?

Comment: And you should specify the experience. If you route directly to that view, what would happen if user wants to go back? (since there will be no back). Don't you mean presenting the yellow view without animation by saying "directly" ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini - When tapping from home screen, the first screen the user should see is the yellow screen. When user closes the yellow screen, the first screen the user should see is the home screen.

Comment: What is `Utils.handleEditNote(rootViewControlle...`